# For comprehension with IO-monad in Scala

Tags: scala, io, scalaz

I have the following in my Scala

```
import scalaz.effect.IO
val i: Iterator[IO[List[String]]] = null

val ii: Iterator[IO[List[String]]] = for{ //This does not compile
  io <- i;
  lst <- io
} yield lst
```

Why? What's wrong?

I expected the `ii` is completely the same as `i`. But it refuses to compile:

```
Error:(12, 11) type mismatch;
 found   : scalaz.effect.IO[List[String]]
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[scalaz.effect.IO[List[String]]]
      lst <- io
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`flatMap` in scala**

Recall that for-comprehensions are just sugared calls to `flatMap`:

```
for {
  a <- expr  //expr must return M[A] such that M has a 
             //flatMap method: flatMap[B](f: A => N[B]) for some N

  b <- f(a)  //f(a) must be an N[B]
  ...
```

**Your question**

Here is the signature of `Iterator.flatMap`

```
def flatMap[B](f: A => GenTraversableOnce[B]): Iterator[B]
```

But you were attempting to supply a function returning an `IO[B]`:

```
lst <- io //You cannot just have `io` on the right here
```

hence the compilation error.

**`flatMap` in scala again**

Scala's `flatMap <~> for-comprehension` conversions as they apply to collection types (and Option) are (in my opinion) confusing as they allow you to *switch between different types of Monad* (e.g. List/Option/Set etc). For example, what is the type of `x` here?

```
val x = 
  for  {
    i <- List(1, 2, 3)
    j <- Option(i + 1)
    k <- Stream(i, j)
  } yield k
```

**Monads in scalaz**

Having a closer look at `scalaz.Monad`'s `flatMap`:

```
trait Monad[M[_]] {
  def flatMap[A, B](ma: M[A])(f: A => M[B]): M[B]
}
```

The type of `M` is always fixed. That is, in this comprehension:

```
lazy val ma: M[A] = ???
for (a <- ma; b <- f(a)) yield b
```

The result type of the function `f` *must be in `M[B]` for some `B`*. Whilst sometimes this can be a little irritating, it has the advantage of being **completely predictable**. You never get confused about *what monad your for comprehension is in*.

**Back to the question**

It is not obvious what you want, but here are a few suggestions:

```
i.toStream.sequence.map(flatten) //IO[Stream[String]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` and `io` must be of the same monad:

```
io <- i   // i is an Iterator[...]
lst <- io // io is an IO[List[String]]
```

Comment: Don't quite understand... What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

When using IO and for-comprehensions, one option is to use .unsafeToFuture in your for comprehension. In your example, this would be:

```
val ii: Iterator[IO[List[String]]] = for{ 
  io <- i;
  lst <- io.unsafeToFuture()
} yield lst
```